# Variable not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django and trying to configure `python-decouple` to use .env variables. I am getting `DB_PASSWORD not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.` when trying to run the server. The .env file is located in the root directory. Here is my code:

**settings.py**

```
import os
from decouple import config

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_development',
        'USER': "db_user",
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
    }
}
```

**my_app.env**

```
DB_PASSWORD=my_password
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the name of the file: `my_app.env` must be `.env`.

From the [`source`](https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-decouple/blob/master/decouple.py) code:

```
class AutoConfig(object):
    """
    Autodetects the config file and type.
    """
    SUPPORTED = {
        'settings.ini': RepositoryIni,
        '.env': RepositoryEnv,
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I misunderstood the directions.

Comment: Where I create .env file? And declare all my project variables?

Comment: I have a .env file created in my dist folder - and it's still giving the error. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @enyfour5 it is going to look in the root dir of the project by the default, see: https://github.com/HBNetwork/python-decouple/blob/860969c0bc7ea9f6815447b498cbaf206813865b/tests/test_env.py#L57