# How to set up separate .env for development and production using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Coming from an environment where I was manually doing a ssh into the remote server, doing a git pull and creating my `.env`(since it is gitignored), how do I separate development `.env` and a production `.env`. I used docker-machine to create an AWS EC2 instance. I created a `production.yml` and did `docker-compose -f production.yml up -d`. The container in the EC2 machine picked up my development `.env` which is not what I want.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev git jpeg-dev zlib-dev libmagic
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /writer-api
COPY requirements.txt /writer-api/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /writer-api/requirements.txt
COPY . /writer-api/
WORKDIR /writer-api
```

**production.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: gunicorn writer.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
    environment:
      DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      SENDGRID_API_KEY: ${SENDGRID_API_KEY}
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME: ${AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    expose:
      - "8000"
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: "redis:alpine"
  celery:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: celery -A writer worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/writer-api
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  celery-beat:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: celery -A writer beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/writer-api
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup the `compose` files for `production` and `dev` in seperate folders and put `.env` file in those folders

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. I have moved `docker-compose.yml` to `compose/dev/docker-compose.yml`. Docker compose still looks for `.env` and `Dockerfile` in the root

Comment: I fired it up with `docker-compose -f compose/dev/docker-compose.yml up -d`

Comment: you need to be in the folder `compose/dev/` as working directory so compose see only on `.env` , so cd to the folder and run `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Did that, the env variables were picked. But still getting `Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile`

Comment: add the context in your compose the context should be a relative path to your compose, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context

Comment: Not quite, I have added `context: ./../../` under `build`. But it seems context, nullifies the whole effort of moving the `.env` to `compose/dev/.env` since it is still looking in the root of the project, where the `Dockefile` is located

Comment: no that context will be used for building the image compose will still looks to the working directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199250/discussion-between-thetypan-and-linpy).

Comment: not working. I created `compose/dev/docker-compose.yml` and `compose/dev/.env`. I made the folder my working directory and did `docker-compose build`. The errors encountered made me update yml file with the following changes. I updated the path to nginx, added `context: ./../../` to each service with the key `build`. That was successful. Second step was `docker-compose up`. The errors had me change the volume of each service with key `build` to `-.:/home/user`. The envs were still not recognized by my app

Comment: There error I was getting was due to `python-decouple` trying to read from `.env` which I had removed. I changed to `os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741193/variable-not-found-declare-it-as-envvar-or-define-a-default-value

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can export the environment shell variable & then use the `.env` as per the environment. Create a `dev.env` & `prod.env` file in the workspace.

Sample compose -

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '80'
    env_file:
      - ${ENVIRON}.env
```

Build for DEV -

```
export ENVIRON=dev
docker-compose up -d
```

Build for PROD -

```
export ENVIRON=prod
docker-compose up -d
```

This way you will be able to leverage same compose file for DEV & PROD environments.

Comment: I have tried this approach before. I created a `dev.env` and `prod.env`. However, when I added the `env_file: ./env/dev.env` in the web service, the env variables were not still available.

Comment: @ vivekyad4v `WARNING: The DEBUG variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.` Same to the rest of the variables. Which led me to further research on the difference between `.env` file and `env_file` and I just still can't get my head around it.

Comment: env_file will be available in the container `.env` in compose file itself

Comment: @vivekyad4v I removed environment key from `docker-compose.yml` as hinted by @LinPy above. Its working fine

Comment: Glad to hear it, thanks for letting me know. I won't really suggest maintaining different directories and dockerfiles in case you have put segregation based on environment variables.